# gdal_retile for big mosaic file

Tags: geoserver, gdal, tiles

I have some big mosaic files (about 3GB, 50k x 50k) and use gdal_retile.py to generate the pyramid tiles for geoserver. It takes very long time to generate all tiles (about one day in my computer).

After googling, I didn't find a parallel version of gdal_retile.py. Are there other methods to generate tiles for big mosaic with higher speed?

Answer (score 1):

I made some 'gentle' additions to the gdal_retile code to make it ***resumable*** in the event of any unavoidable/intentional interruptions. You can find it here [gdal_retile_multi](https://github.com/cm0001/gdal_retile_multi)

You can also use it in a multiple-copy way to tile a large raster dataset in a ***divide-and-conquer*** approach.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I have implemented a R script wrapping with gdal_retile which can run in parallel.